# How to get mean of rnorm dataset in R?

Tags: r

The question is.. Generate 30 random numbers that follow the normal distribution of the following values: mean=0, sd=sqrt(2). Create 50 of these datasets to average each and draw a histogram with these 50 means.

I wanna get hist consisted of 50 graphs.(as I understood)
so I tried this.

```
> x<-matrix(rnorm(30,0,sqrt(2)), nrow=30, ncol=50)
> x
> m=50
> mx=rep(0,m)
> for(i in 1:m){mx[i]=mean(x[,i])}
> hist(mx, labels=TRUE)`
```

But I can't get what I want. All mean values are same.
So I tried another.

```
> nx=rep(0,n)
> for(i in 1:n){nx[i]=mean(rnorm(30,0,sqrt(2)))}
> hist(nx, labels=TRUE)
```

But I think this one is wrong too..
I just wanna get 50 values of mean(rnorm(30,0,sqrt(2)) using for loop. How can I get this??
Plz help me..

Comment: Change to: `x <- matrix(rnorm(30*50,0,sqrt(2)), nrow=30, ncol=50)`

Comment: Alternatively you can try: `mx <- sapply(1:50, function(i) mean(rnorm(30,0,sqrt(2))))`

Comment: The reason you did not get what you want is that you only selected 30 random values, enough for the first column, but you told R you wanted a matrix with 50 columns of 30 values. R assumed you wanted to copy the values in the  first column into the next 49 columns. R regularly recycles values if you do not provide enough.